# getUserMedia running from inside a local html page

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

I am trying to use my webcam from [this demo](http://www.andismith.com/examples/blog/getusermedia-simple/) and it works fine. But when I copy/paste this code to a local html page and try to run it from my local computer, it throws an error "Please accept the getUserMedia permissions! Refresh to try again."

Is that something about the same origin policy, or some restrictions like that?

Comment: A lot of stuff in Chrome doesn't work running from the `file:` scheme. You'll need to set up a simple HTTP server, or run chrome with the flag `--allow-file-access-from-files`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I set up a simple node server and it works fine now. I just was wondering if the issue was that :). Now I get it. Thanks!